# filetype is empty when editing a file

Tags: filetype

I want to source file `csv.vim` when editing a csv file. But when I editing a .csv file , it is not sourced and `set filetype?` returns `filetype=`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to check out [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and [edit] in the minimal reproducing vimrc you end up with. You might also want to check the output of `:filetype` to make sure filetype detection is on.

Comment: I believe `csv` is not by default detected. You need a plugin like my csv plugin for that

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I think it's worth it to write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

CSV Files are not by default recognized by Vim. You need to install a plugin like my [csv plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/) to have detect `.csv` files correctly.